# Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

Let us assume we have two matrices $A$, $B$ for which one can run the Cholesky decomposition and we get $U \times U^{T} = A$ and $V \times V^{T} = B$ where $U$ and $V$ are lower triangular matrices.

Knowing that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ B^T&A \end{bmatrix}$ is positive definite can we compute the Cholesky decomposition of it using only the matrices $U$ and $V$?

Thanks,
Bogdan.

Comment: Cholesky decomposition implies positive-semidefiniteness. Consider $A=0$ and $B=1$, then the new block matrix is not positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks, but under the assumption that the new matrix is positive-semidefinite can we still compute the factorization only out of matrix U and V?